# How to display items not in actual list but are in expected list using fluentassertions?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Lets say I have 2 dictionary objects: `Dictionary<string, object> dictA`, `Dictionary<string, object> dictB`. I'm doing the following when comparing them:

```
dictB.ShouldBeEquivalentTo<T>(dictA);
```

When the total items do not match, I just get a message

> Expected member dictB to be a dictionary with 26 item(s), but found 23 item(s).

How can I make it show what items are missing between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I can't do that just yet. I recommend you file a feature request on www.fluentassertions.com